# LPM raspberry pi 4B extinction mechanism

Tags: pi-4, hardware, power, power-management

I am contacting you because I would like to know how the LPM (Low Power Mode) mechanism works on the raspberry pi 4B.
In order to take advantage of this feature, according to the [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#POWER_OFF_ON_HALT)
put POWER_OFF_ON_HALT = 1 and WAKE_ON_GPIO = 0.

When you send a shutdown command (example: `sudo halt`) via the terminal, the raspberry pi shuts down properly and goes into LPM.
To turn it back on, you have to set the GLOBAL_EN signal to zero, then when it is set to one, the raspberry pi restarts. This manipulation is manual and requires for example a momentary push button.

When we read the [PMIC specifications](https://assets.maxlinear.com/web/documents/mxl7704.pdf), when GLOBAL_EN = 0, all the regulated outputs turn off.
A priori, in the case of POWER_OFF_ON_HALT = 1, it is not GLOBAL_EN that is used to turn off the raspberry pi. GLOBAL_EN is just used for rebooting the raspberry pi.

My question: by which signal / pin, the processor sends the order to the PMIC to turn off the regulated outputs?

Thank you

Comment: Did the answer not help? Maybe consider explaining what it is you're trying to do & we may be able to provide something more useful?

Answer (score 1):

> My question: by which signal / pin, the processor sends the order to the PMIC to turn off the regulated outputs?

In section 2B of the RPi 4B [schematic](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpi4/raspberry-pi-4-reduced-schematics.pdf), you will see a connection to `GLOBAL_RESET`. This is the signal from the "processor" that turns off the PMIC's **regulated** outputs.